# Force max-height on a CSS grid row

Tags: css

I have a simple grid with 2 rows: one serves as a header, the other one is a list of items. I want my grid to have a max height, and I want to be able to scroll my list of items.

[Link to the codepen](https://codepen.io/Sashkan/pen/OJwZBgq)

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="two">
    Two
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <div class="body">
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px min-content;
  max-height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.two {
  background: green;
}

.three {
  background: #00000044;
  max-height: 400px;
}

.body {
  max-width: 400px;
  background: orange;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

My .grid item has a max height, but still, if I had more items to my list, the whole grid expands. Is there a way to make sure my max height is taken into account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only scroll the list of items and keep the header in the same position you can use `position: sticky`, updated example:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px min-content;
  max-height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.two {
  background: green;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.three {
  background: #00000044;
}

.body {
  max-width: 400px;
  background: orange;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="two">
    Two
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    <div class="body">
      <p>Section first</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section</p>
      <p>Section last</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of overflow hidden use auto

code :

```
.grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 50px min-content;
        max-height: 300px;
        background: blue;
        overflow-y: hidden;
       }

 .two {
        background: green;
      }

 .three {
        background: #00000044;
        max-height: 400px;
      }

 .body {
        max-width: 400px;
        background: orange;
        margin: auto;
        max-height: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
       }
```

Comment: If I do so, the whole grid is scrolled, including the header

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you can't set max-height to 300px on both .grid and .body ?

```
.body { max-height: 300px; }
```